# Ударение в слове "петля"

Tags: орфоэпия

Какое ударение в слове "петля": пЕтля или петлЯ?

Comment: Есть также форма п**е**тельный: петельный шов. Налицо очередная пара типа "ноль-нуль". В одних устойчивых выражениях ударение на первый, в других - на последний слог. При проникновении формы петл**я** появился дериват петлев**о**й.

Answer (score 2):

Это слово, в отношении которого нормативность сменилась буквально на глазах.
Я еще хорошо помню те времена, когда старая норма п**е**тля считалась единственно правильной, словари для дикторов приводили её года до 80-го. И это было не просто на бумаге, носители старых норм реально только так и говорили, хотя еще в 60-х начали появляться стихийные колебания. Сейчас предпочтительным вариантом является уже новый - петл**я**, старый вариант уходит и кажется архаичным, если не неправильным.

О причинах, как и почти всегда в таких случаях, можно только гадать, хотя я не исключаю, что тут не последнюю роль сыграли авиаторы со своими мертвыми петлями и петлей Нестерова. В профессиональном жаргоне я старого произношения не слышал никогда, хотя был связан с носителями этого профжаргона со школьных еще лет.

Answer (score 2):

Также изложенная позиция подтверждается относительным прилагательным "петлевой". Такая парадигма свойственна аналогичным существительным с ударением на второй слог, а не первый слог  (корма - кормовой, езда - ездовой, крупа - крупяной, принцип действует и для таких, более распространенных вариантов, как река - речной, рука - ручной...), - обратите внимание, что "звездный" образовано не от "звезда", а от "звёзды"; тогда как от существительных с ударением на первый слог в норме прилагательное образуется иначе (прачка - прачечная, варка - варочный, шкура - шкурный, марка - марочный и т.п.; то же подтверждается притяжательными прилагательными беличий, мамин и т.п.). **Если бы правильным был вариант *"пЕтля", язык просто не породил бы такого прилагательного, как "петлевой".**

Comment: Почему не породил бы? А отраслевой? От слова отрасль, с ударением на первый слог. А проверка глаголом (петля-петлять) вообще некорректна. Как-то неубедительно выглядят аргументы в защиту новой нормы.

Comment: Юлия, не надо спорить таким образам. Дайте лучше свой полноценный ответ. А что касается текстов от некоего eee, так очевидно, что его теории критики не выдерживают. У него все построено на том, что п**е**тли - это, дескать, "смещение" ударения, а вот петл**я**ть - это не смещение. А почему не наоборот. И почему рассматривать петлевой, а не п**е**тельный? Или не п**е**телька? Не стоит обсуждать серьезно, дайте свой полноценный ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Орфографический словарь под редакцией Лопатина допускает два варианта: п**е**тля и петл**я**.

В словаре "Русское словесное ударение". Словарь нарицательных имён.
Автор М. В. Зарва. М.: ЭНАС, 2001 ударение таково: петл**я**, -и; мн. п**е**тли,п**е**тель, п**е**тлям .

Comment: Ничего себе!___

Answer (score 1):

"П**е**тля" — это, так сказать, "малый" русский язык, язык гуманитарной интеллигенции, потомков выходцев из т. н. местечек. Это из той же оперы, что и "м**о**ста" вместо более естественного "мост**а**". Да не смутит никого тот факт, что представители этой прослойки очень активны, и создается впечатление, что они везде. С экранов ТВ и из радиоточек нас постоянно последние 25 лет "знатоки языка" уверяют, что только "мОста" (р. п. от "мост"), только "пЕтля" и т. д., невзирая на то, что сам язык содержит все указания на то, что как раз "мост**а**" и "петл**я**". Какие это указания? Очень простые: есть форма "(на) мост**у**" - это так называемый местный падеж, в котором окончание "-у" — ударное (на ветру, на бегу и пр.). Другими словами, в слове "мост" нет никакого фиксированного ударения на корень, ударение здесь подвижное, как и вообще свойственно русскому языку (стол — стол**а**); обратный случай — исключение, это слова, которые ощущаются как иностранные, например "торт", хотя и "торт" имеет просторечную форму "в торт**е**" наряду с нормативным "в т**о**рте"; таким словам местный падеж вообще чужд, т. к. он архаичный и сочетается только с "родными" словами (хотя бывают исключения и тут — например, "шкаф"). Поэтому говорить "у м**о**ста" — не (совсем) русский язык, можно назвать это "альтернативный" или "малый" русский язык. Нормальный, естественно звучащий вариант ударения для этой словоформы — у мост**а**, например "у Литейного мост**а**".

В случае "петля" проверка (поверка самим языком) — например, глагол "петл**я**ть". Если бы было "п**е**тля", ударение было бы другое. 
Что касается мн. ч. "п**е**тли", то здесь это типичное для форм множественного числа смещение ударения на корень (как звезда — звёзды).

Answer (score 1):

Да, определить точно, ***когда*** и **по какой причине** сместилось ударение, практически невозможно. ***А было оно таким*** (печатный вариант):

**пЕтля**, *р.мн. **пЕтель***
Орфографический словарь, проф. Д.Н.Ушаков, **1938**

**пЕтля**, -и, *р.мн. **пЕтель***
Орфографический словарь русского языка под.ред. С.И.Ожегова и А.Б.Шапиро, **1957**
Словарь русского языка в четырех томах, том III, **1959**

**пЕтля**, -и  и **петлЯ**, -и, *мн. **пЕтли, пЕтель, пЕтлям***
Толковый словарь русского языка, С.И.Ожегов и Н.Ю.Шведова, **1996**

**пЕтля**, -и  и **петлЯ**, -и, *мн. **пЕтли, пЕтель, пЕтлям***
Орфографический словарь русского языка, В.В.Бурцева, **2003**

P.S. Где-то был орфографический словарь семидесятых годов. Как только найду - сразу добавлю информацию.

***Постбиблиотечное ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ***

**пЕтля**
Словарь русского языка, С.И.Ожегов, под.ред. Н.Ю.Шведовой, **1972**

**пЕтля**
Орфографический словарь русского языка под ред. С.Г.Бархударова, И.Ф.Протченко и Л.И.Скворцова, **1974**

**пЕтля**
Словарь русского языка в четырех томах (гл.редактор А.П.Евгеньева), том III, **1983**

Ещё одно:
**пЕтля**
АН СССР, ИРЯ, Орфографический словарь русского языка под ред. С.Г.Бархударова, И.Ф.Протченко и Л.И.Скворцова, **1989**

Comment: "Причины" тут нет и быть не может. Можно в лучшем случае фиксировать лишь некую тенденцию. Но в отношении этого слова даже тенденции не просматривалось. А что касается "когда" - так это более или менее установлено. к началу 80-х. Сравнивать данные разных словарей бесперспективно. один опаздывают, другие всегда бегут впереди паровоза...  Если есть возможность, то надо смотреть по разным изданиям одного словаря, Аванесова-Еськовой, например или Зарвы. Зарва, пожалуй, даже лучше, поскольку он традиционно  избегает всех "допустимых" вариантов и как правило дает только предпочтительный.

Comment: Но у меня под рукой Зарвы нет. А Аванесов-84 дает уже петл**я** как первый и п**е**тля как равноправный. Более раннего тож нет. Ожегов-64 - п**е**тля и петл**я**, но он же не орфоэпический.

Comment: Интересно-интересно! Попробую после праздников сползать в библиотеку, покопаться... Когда я взяла домой четырехтомник русского языка, 1957-1961,  который списывали, на меня и так смотрели как на дуру.